# AWS load balancer in front of EKS and Lambdas/API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, amazon-eks

We have an ALB in front of our EKS cluster ([ALB Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-alb-ingress-controller)) serving our micro-services on
`api.mycompany.com`

We developed some REST API endpoints using Lambdas/API Gateway served on
`new-service.mycompany.com`

Everything works fine but we would like to serve these new services under the same domain:
`api.mycompany.com/new-service`

I don't really see how should we do.... Is this even possible?

Thanks for you help :-)

Comment: Just from curiosity, Why would you like to do that?

Comment: We prefer to have all our services served on a single domain name:  `api.mycompany.com/service1` (from EKS), `api.mycompany.com/service2` (from Lambda). Instead of `service1..mycompany.com` and `service2.mycompany.com`...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this might help: [AWS ALB Ingress Controller](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/).

Comment: Thanks but I don't see anything about Lambdas or API Gateway used by these Lambdas...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manage it via the API gateway. try this:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/integrate-amazon-api-gateway-with-amazon-eks/